# duplicate row values for same ID

Tags: r, rstudio

I have looked at the various threads and sadly the answers provided are not working. I am merging two files. Both files have common column names. I want the two data sets to merge for the same time point, however when I use the command `s3<-merge(s1,s2,all=TRUE)`, it gives me a file as follows:

[image: screenshot of file]

I would like the duplicate time points to be removed.

If I use `s3<-merge(s1,s2,all.x=TRUE)`, then none of the data from s2 gets merged.

When reading the data file I am using `s2<-read.csv('X.csv',stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question to include [reproducible data and code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: How about ``merge(merge(df1, df2, by='id', all=T), df3, by='id', all=T)``? or use `cbind` method.

Comment: actually let me re phrase - so ultimately what i want is this - for the same ID, i want to time match different columns